# How to override Selenium Webdriver FindElement and add a wait to it?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver with C# and I'm wondering if there's a way to override the FindElement method? What I'd like to do - if possible - is to add an extra parameter and code to the method that would force it to wait for the element to be visible before proceeding.
For example, it would then be something like this:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("orion.dialog.box.ok"), 60).Click();
```

This would wait up to 60 seconds for the element to appear and be available to click.

Any ideas how to do this?
Thanks,
John

Comment: one of the ways is to add implicit wait ((stackoverflow.com/a/11244854/2504101). The other is to use EventFiringWebDriver which allows to add any action (even highlight element) before/after action is permormed stackoverflow.com/a/23787258/2504101

Answer (score 0):

You could use ImplicitWait for this. You can create a new user defined function to accept the By object and the timeout seconds and have the function return the IWebElement, something like below:

```
 IWebElement elem = MyOwnGetElement(By.id("test"),60);
```

The above function might have the below code, where time_out_sec is the function parameter.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time_out_sec));

driver.Url = "http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading";
IWebElement myDynamicElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("someDynamicElement"));
```

Comment: An implicit wait is only going to be concerned with the element being there, but being *visible* is a different story.

Comment: After being present in DOM, the element can be checked for visiblity.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add it as an extension method. Pseudo code:

```
public static IWebElement WaitForAndFindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by)
{
    // do a wait
    // something like...
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)); // hard code it here if you want to avoid each calling method passing in a value

    return wait.Until(webDriver => 
        {
            if (webDriver.FindElement(by).Displayed)
            {
                return webDriver.FindElement(by);
            }
            return null; // returning null with force the wait class to iterate around again.
        });
}
```

Just to state, an implicit wait is going to be part one of your solution. It will cause Selenium to wait up to 60 seconds for an element to be **present in DOM** but being **visible** is something entirely different.

`.Displayed` will handle that, and it must be handled within a `WebDriverWait`.

Answer (score 0):

I am coding with Selenium for 6+ months and I had the same problem as yours. I have created this extension method and it works for me every time.

What the code does is:
During 20 seconds, it checks each 500ms, whether or not the element is present on the page. If after 20 seconds, it's not found, it will throw an exception.
This will help you make a dynamic wait.

```
  public static class SeleniumExtensionMethods {
      public static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
      public static void SafeClick(this IWebElement webElement) {
          try {
              wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(webElement)).Click();
          } catch (TargetInvocationException ex) {
              Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
          }

      }
```

and then use it like this:

```
IWebElement x = driver.FindElement(By.Id("username"));
x.SafeClick();
```